# Meaning of phrase "Jacke wie Hose"

Tags: phrase

What does the phrase "Jacke wie Hose" mean? Can anyone explain in which contexts this phrase can be used.

Comment: Similar expressions: "Pott wie Deckel" and "Gehopst wie gesprungen"

Comment: "It's all the same to me."

Answer (score 5):

Both are items of clothing historically tailored from the same fabric, so there is little difference. Cf. the English "it's as broad as it's long". It's rather colloquial, though.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly agree with rather colloquial. In my opinion, it's neither formal nor colloquial. It wouldn't be found in a research funding application, but I believe to have seen it in newspapers such as *Die Zeit*. The actual translated meaning is *It doesn't matter*. (but that's not as nicely idiomatic as your one ;))

Answer (score 4):

Es handelt sich um eine umgangssprachliche Redewendung, die angewendet werden kann, wenn es darum geht zwischen zwei Optionen zu wählen. *Jacke wie Hose* bedeutet dann, dass es egal ist, welche Option gewählt wird.